# Numpy.NET Getting Values

Tags: c#, .net, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to "convert" the Keras notebooks made by F. Chollet to C# / .NET applications. You can find them [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks). I am specifically working on "3.5 - Movie Reviews" as of right now.

The problem is, I can't convert my NDarrays to C# arrays to use the values. I tried [this](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET) method (in *README - section Performance Considerations*), but I get random values or Python Runtime errors.

```cpp
using Keras.Datasets;
using Numpy;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassifyingMovieReviews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Variables
        NDarray train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels;
        NDarray x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test;

        public NDarray VectorizeSequences(NDarray sequence, int dimension = 10000)
        {
            NDarray output = np.zeros((sequence.size, dimension));
            int[] value = { 1 };
            
            // this works to extract the first line (as an NDarray!)
            NDarray line0 = sequence[0];
            
            // nothing works (of those three)
            var raw_data_1 = sequence.GetData<int>();
            Console.WriteLine("raw_data_1: " + raw_data_1);

            var raw_data_2 = sequence.GetData<float>();
            Console.WriteLine("raw_data_2: " + raw_data_2);

            var raw_data_3 = sequence.GetData<double>();
            Console.WriteLine("raw_data_3: " + raw_data_3);
            
            return output;
        }

        private void ReadData()
        {
            // parameters
            int top_words = 10000;

            // the data, split between train and test sets
            ((train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels)) = IMDB.LoadData(num_words: top_words);

            // Our vectorized training & test data
            x_train = VectorizeSequences(train_data);
            x_test = VectorizeSequences(test_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my train_data and test_data appear to be correct, they look like this:

```
train_data = {
    [
        list([1, 14, 22, ..., 178, 32])
        list([1, 194, 1153, ..., 95])
        list([1, 14, 47, 8, ..., 2])
        ...
        list([1, 17, 6, ..., 131, 9])
    ]
}
Numpy.NDarray
```

Comment: You may also find the following from Microsoft helpful. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet

Comment: You can also debug python code in Visual Studio, stepping through and using watch etc. Right click the .py file and you should have option to Debug run it from VS. If not you might need to setup the Python tools etc for Visual Studio. That has been very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: I went through Github source code to find a solution*

- **GetData<>()**

This method only accepts a small number of types. I tested them all but nothing worked.
I suspect it does not work like it should because I don't have a multidimensional NDarray, but instead a NDarray of Python.Runtime 'list' objects.

```cs
using Keras.Datasets;
using Numpy;

// Variables
NDarray train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels;
NDarray x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test;
int top_words = 10000;

// the data, split between train and test sets
((train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels)) = IMDB.LoadData(
        num_words: top_words
);

// GetData testing
byte[] byteToCsharp = train_data.GetData<byte>();
short[] shortToCsharp = train_data.GetData<short>();
int[] intToCsharp = train_data.GetData<int>();
long[] longToCsharp = train_data.GetData<long>();
float[] floatToCsharp = train_data.GetData<float>();
double[] doubleToCsharp = train_data.GetData<double>();
bool[] boolToCsharp = train_data.GetData<bool>();
```

The `GetData` function signature can be found [here](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/blob/945d1568c2dfa2d88e6293a2b019f95df9a4bc94/src/Numpy/Models/NDarray.cs). Alternatively, go to the SciSharp/Numpy.NET repository and search for "GetData" in the search bar.

- **PadSequences()**

This is the answer for manipulating the IMDB dataset in C# and vectorizing the sequences. Note that it does not solve my problem of converting the NDarray obtained from IMDB.LoadData() into C# native arrays.

```cs
using Keras.Datasets;
using Keras.PreProcessing.sequence;
using Numpy;

// Variables
NDarray train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels;
NDarray x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test;
int top_words = 10000;

((x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)) = IMDB.LoadData(
        num_words: top_words
);

int max_words = 500;
x_train = SequenceUtil.PadSequences(x_train, maxlen: max_words);
x_test = SequenceUtil.PadSequences(x_test, maxlen: max_words);
```

Instead, it directly calls a function from Python if I understand the function correctly. You can find it [here](https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET/blob/c1eecbd9235a2606d5b58c1b809e2e0fafa8c296/Keras/PreProcessing/Sequence.cs), or by searching for "PadSequences" in the search bar on the SciSharp/Keras.NET repository.

Comment: Your proposed solution and conclusion are not quite right, so I'd say the question is not closed (by virtue of your own answer), however, I have added a detailed answer for you, and to help others who come across this question, which was a good post. I hope that helps, good luck with your ML in C# ! Thanks.

Comment: Answer updated for the "copying Chollet notebooks" part.
Still not done for the "getting back the value as C# native arrays" part though.

Comment: Yes GetData<T>() is what is used to get the underlying data (assuming it is of the correct type). Yes if you "don't have a multidimensional NDarray, but instead a NDarray of Python.Runtime 'list' objects" then it's not going to work directly like that. You will need to access the underlying data first. GetData<T>() works with NDarray objects that are used as such and extracts them to a 1D array (where possible).

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

The generic **`GetData<T>()` method** on `NDarray` is **what you want**.

You just need to:

- use the correct data type
- be careful of the NDarray's shape

You can get exceptions such as:

- `System.InvalidOperationException`
- `Python.Runtime.PythonException`

if you get either of those two bits wrong e.g. wrong Type for the generic or trying to get an array from an NDarray (or dimension or slice of it) that contains data that is not itself an array. You don't need to code your own `ParseManuallyIntoArrayOfInts`

### Example

```cs
using Numpy;

    
var nDimArray = np.array(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).reshape(2, 2);    
int[] allElementsFlattened = nDimArray.GetData<int>();
    
int[] arrayFromDim0 = nDimArray[0].GetData<int>();
int[] arrayFromDim1 = nDimArray[1].GetData<int>();
```

whereas trying to get data of **wrong type**:

```
var x = nDimArray[1].GetData<object>() 
threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

whereas trying to get data that **doesn't match the shape**:

```
var x = nDimArray[0][0].GetData<int>() 
threw an exception of type 'Python.Runtime.PythonException'
```

### Stringifying C# Arrays

Your Console.WriteLine() is not going to give you what I expect you want/expect. You *do* need to do *a little work* to turn e.g. int[] into a string (over and above the default output of type).

To get a useful string representation try something like this:

```csharp
    Console.WriteLine($"[{String.Join(", ", nDimArray.GetData<int>()) }]");
```

Which would give you e.g.:

```
"[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

I'd **recommend** using **breakpoints and watches** to look at what is in your NDarray objects at different steps of your code.

### Simple Helper Function

Or if you have a lot of NDarray using inference code to work through you might also create a little helper function to write core details to Debug / Console e.g.:

```csharp
public static void DisplayNDarray(NDarray nDarray, string name = "")
{
    Debug.WriteLine($">> DisplayDetails {name}:");
    Debug.WriteLine($"size {nDarray.size} shape {nDarray.shape} dims {nDarray.ndim}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"mean {nDarray.mean()} std {nDarray.std()} min {nDarray.min()} max {nDarray.max()}");
}
```

### Extra Helper Function

And for **when you know the underlying type** of the data you can use another simple helper to visualise the data as a string

```csharp
public static void DisplayNDarrayData<TElementType>(NDarray nDarray)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{String.Join(", ", nDarray.GetData<TElementType>())}]");
}
```

Called like:

```csharp
DisplayNDarrayData<int>(nDimArray);
```

Comment: I already knew a lot of things you introduced, but I learnt some things as well. I'll try to find some time to look at it once more, and update my answer to a clean solution if I find one.